Get documents according to a value of a field such that the field exists on some documents and not on others
I'm working on cloud firestore and let's assume this is how my documents are structured in a collection:
{
    'name': 'something'
    'age': 23,
}

And I've some 200-300 users, and I'm storing their data like this. Now let's say that I had to add a new field favorite_color. So I added it to all the new user accounts that are being created right now. So now some documents look like as follows:
{
        'name': 'something'
        'age': 23,
        'favorite_color': 'red',
}

Now I wanted to fetch these documents with the following query:
Get all docs where favorite_color is empty string or if the field just doesn't exist. I've no idea how to get this done. Can this even be done? Any help will be appreciated.

Firestore queries are based on the item existing in an index. If a document doesn't have a certain field, it will not exists in an index on that field - and thus can't be found there. So: there is no way to get documents without a specific field.

I'm not sure how would this work with query but you can try the following code:
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData() async {
            try {
              final list =
                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").get();

              /// Result List
              final List<Map<String, dynamic>> res = [];

              for (final element in list.docs) {
                final data = element.data();

                if (data.containsKey("fieldName")) {
                  if ((data['fieldName'] as String).isEmpty) {
                    /// if Field is Empty
                    /// add to result list
                    res.add(data);
                  } else {
                    /// Handle Data with non empty fieldName
                  }
                } else {
                  /// if Field is not present
                  /// add to result list
                  res.add(data);
                }
              }

              return res;
            } catch (e) {
              print(e.toString());
              rethrow;
            }
          }



Get all docs where favorite_color is empty string or if the field just
doesn't exist.

These are two different cases.
Let's first start with querying for all documents for which the favorite_color field doesn't exist: This is actually not possible with Firestore. The query mechanism is based on indexes and it is not possible to index a field that does not exist.
Then, for the other case, i.e. querying for all documents for which the favorite_color field is an empty string, you can use the following Query:
final stateQuery = collectionRef.where("favorite_color", isEqualTo: "");

